# Programmatically get routes in Play! Framework 2.5.x

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, swagger

In the `play-swagger` module, we used the `play.routes.compiler.RoutesFileParser` to get all registered routes from Play and further parse them to an API documentation:

```
val parsedRoutes = RoutesFileParser.parse(new File(app.classloader.getResource(routesFile).toURI))
val routes = parsedRoutes.right.get.collect {
  case (route: PlayRoute) => {
    logger.debug(s"Adding route '$route'")
    Seq(route.copy(path = route.path.copy(parts = StaticPart(prefix + "/") +: route.path.parts)))
  }
  case (include: PlayInclude) => {
    logger.debug(s"Processing route include $include")
    parseRoutesHelper(playRoutesClassNameToFileName(include.router), include.prefix)
  }
}.flatten
```

This results in the following error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/routes/compiler/RoutesFileParser`

It seems that the `RoutesFileParser` became private in Play! 2.5.

What is the correct way to fetch all Play routes like in the example above?

Comment: I have checked the git history of RoutesFileParser and I did not find any important change from 2.4.0. The object is public with the public parse method and the class is private as it was for play 2.4.0. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/commits/master/framework/src/routes-compiler/src/main/scala/play/routes/compiler/RoutesFileParser.scala It is not an answer to your question but maybe the problem is elsewhere, missing libraries, wrong versions, ...

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a dependency problem. Check the dependencyTree.

If it's not already there, then add the following to the build file:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "routes-compiler" % "2.5.0"
```

Then this will compile and run nicely:

```
val routesURI = app.classloader.getResource("routes").toURI
val parsedRoutes = play.routes.compiler.RoutesFileParser.parse(new File(routesURI))
println(parsedRoutes)
```

(where app is a running instance of play.api.Application)

Answer (score 0):

When looking through the sourcecode of Play, I found that I can use the following:

```
class HomeController @Inject() (router: Provider[Router]) {
....
    router.get().documentation.foreach(println)
....
}
```

This will print out String tuples with HTTP method, path, method invocation. This is how the routes on the DEV 404 page are rendered.